# 32 bit jvm executing batch file fails with 'pnputil.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

I am executing batch file from 32bit Java application. 
This batch/cmd tries to install some drivers using pnputil.exe on windows 7 64 bit and fails  giving - **'pnputil.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command**.

Tried with changing dir to %WINDIR%/System32/ within batch file and calling pnputil.exe without any success.

However similar batch executes fine when run from 64-bit jvm.

What alternatives do I have to install INF files from 32-bit jvm executing batch file on 64-bit Windows 7  ?

Comment: Do you have full path to the pnputil.exe in your batch file?

Comment: yes, tried with full path C:\Windows\System32\PnPutil.exe

Answer (score 0):

I can execute pnpUtil via path **%WINDIR%\sysnative\pnputil.exe** for 32bit JVM.
Though sysnative is not visible via win explorer but it solved my problem.